# Juntar dois df usando a função sqldf

Tags: sql, r

Estou tentando juntar duas tabelas usando o mesmo id da especie, mas não estou conseguindo.

Abaixo seguem os passos:

Importando o arquivo corrigido para o TNRS para o R

```
hp<-fread('tnrs_final.txt', header=T)
```

Agora ligando as tabelas usando o ID unico da especie:

```
library(sqldf) #pacote 

juncao_dfs<-sqldf('select * from df_total left join hp on df_total.id_species=hp.user_id') #df_total é o outro df que quero juntar com hp.
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem no console:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 9.9 Mb

Como faço para contornar isso? Existem outros pacotes ou funções que fazem isso?

Comment: Esse erro acontece quando o seu programa precisa de mais RAM do que o que está disponível no seu computador. Pode ser que seja isso mesmo, e aí vc vai precisar trabalhar off-mememory usando algum banco de dados como SQLite (tem o pacote RSQLite). Pode ser que seja um erro... O left join pode duplicar muitas linhas se os dios data frames contiverem muitas linhas com o mesmo userid.

Comment: Pode ser isso, mas o tamanho do vetor que não pode ser alocado é muito pequeno. @Bruno Umbelino, não pode fornecer nem uma parte das tabelas? `dput(hp)` e `dput(df_total)` podem nos ajudar a entender o problema.

Comment: Se forem muito grandes pode mandar algo como `dput(head(hp, 100))`

Comment: @TomásBarcellos o tamanho que ele fala é aleatório. Não é o tamanho real, é o tamanho da última alocação que deu erro.

Comment: Claro, mas se deu erro ao alocar um vetor de 10 Mb, é porque tava no limite de uso da RAM. Na minha experiência esse caso é mais comum quando há algum erro semântico no código. Mas claro que pode aparecer em situações de fato limite. Por isso o `dput()` ajudaria :)